# How to add coordinates in Simple Schema as autoValue?

Tags: meteor

Here is the Simple Schema for coordinates:

```
{
  loc: {
        type: Object,
        index: '2dsphere',
        label: "Location",
        autoform: {
                    type: "hidden",
                    omit: true
                    }
        },

  "loc.type": {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ["Point"],
        label: "Start location type"
        },

  "loc.coordinates": {
        type: [Number],
        minCount: 2,
        maxCount: 2,
        decimal: true,
        autoValue: function () {
                    var lat = document.getElementById("latitude");
                    var lng = document.getElementById("longitude");
                    var location1 = [lat, lng];
                    return location1;
                    }
            }
}
```

As method, I used this on server side:

```
Meteor.methods({
    createLocation: function(userID,lat, lng) {
        ComplaintSchema.upsert({_id: userID}, {coordinates: [lat, lng]});
    }
});
```

For client side, I used this:

```
'submit': function () {
        var id = Meteor.userId();
        var lat=document.getElementById("latitude").value;
        var lng=document.getElementById("longitude").value;
        Meteor.call('createLocation',id,lat,lng, function(err){
           if(err) console.log("not going in");
        });
        Router.go('/Home');
    }
```

It is throwing the error "not going in". 
How to insert the values in loc.coordinates, what would be the syntax in that case? Will be it like this:

```
ComplaintSchema.upsert({_id: userID}, {"loc.coordinates": [lat, lng]});
```

It has to add the value for loc.type as point also, how will I do that?

Please assist me.

Thank you in advance.